# Jackson JSON mapping Facebook data

Tags: java, jackson

Sample JSON data from Facebook

```
{
    "1111111" : {
         "home" : false,
         "activities" : "some value"
    },

    "2222222" : {
         "home" : false,
         "activities" : "some value again"
    }
}
```

```
public class Profile{
    private boolean home;
    private String activities;

    // generated setter getter

    public static void main(String[] args) throws JsonParseException, JsonMappingException, IOException {
        ObjectMapper mapper = new ObjectMapper();
        Profile mainProfile = mapper.readValue(new File("data.json"), Profile.class);

        System.out.println(mainProfile.getActivities().size());
    }
}
```

Run above file will produce this error.

```
Unrecognized field "1111111" (Class com.analysis.structure.Profile), not marked as ignorable
```

The problem I'm facing is that how to map that "1111111" value to a variable in a class? If I use @JsonIgnoreProperties(ignoreUnknown=true), it will totally ignore all the josn data, since the first data does not have any tag to map to. How should I map this type of json data into Java using Jackson JSON?

Comment: Correct errors like missing `"` in `"2222222`  and  `;` should be replaced by `,`  check link for more visual insight! [json parser](http://json.parser.online.fr/)

Comment: @MayurPipaliya Sorry. that's a typo. I've fixed that. but still, I have no idea how to map this "1111111" and "2222222"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That does not map to POJOs cleanly, so maybe you should rather bind it to a `Map`, where key is of type `String`, and value some POJO type?